# Nanostores is not working in Astro component

Tags: astrojs, nanostores

*Problem:* So I was able to successfully add nanostores into a React test component that I created **but what I want to do** is be able to **use nanostores in an Astro component** (*.astro). I'm trying to make just a simple web app solely in Astro with no other integrations (React, Vue, Svelte, etc).

```
--Dependencies--
astro: 2.0.18
nanostores: 0.7.4
preact: 10.13.1
@nanostores/preact: 0.3.1
@astrojs/preact: 2.1.0
```

*Attempt:*
I created a simple nanostore here:

```
//userStore.js
import { atom } from 'nanostores';
export const isUserLoggedIn = atom(true);
```

and then imported into my Header.astro component:

```
//Header.astro
---
import { useStore } from '@nanostores/preact';
import { isUserLoggedIn } from '../stores/userStore';
let $isUserLoggedIn = useStore(isUserLoggedIn);
---

<nav>
  <div class='links'>
    <a href='/'>Home</a>
    <a href='/about'>About</a>
    <a href='/blog'>Blog</a>
  </div>
  <div class='links'>
    {
      $isUserLoggedIn ? (
        <a href='/logout'>Logout</a>
      ) : (
        <>
          <a href='/login'>Login</a>
          <a href='/register'>Register</a>
        </>
      )
    }
  </div>
</nav>
```

*The error that I receive:*
[image: The error that I receive]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I noticed that in the astro docs (https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/sharing-state/), they don't recommend using nanostores in .astro files. So I guess I'll just have to use React components

Comment: That error comes from trying to use a hook outside of a component. Indeed, that will not work, you need components.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because `.astro` files are built server side and nano stores are designed to be used client side

If you want conditionally render HTML in a `.astro` file using login sessions you can try using SSR with a server side auth library like [`auth-astro`](https://github.com/nowaythatworked/auth-astro) or [`lucia-auth`](https://lucia-auth.com/)